# JOLT - Permutation transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

My input JSON

```
{
    "title": [
        "vsnu",
        "anothervsnu"
    ]
}
```

MY SPEC

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "title": {
        "*": {
          "$(1)": "Responses[].head",
          "@": "Responses[].name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

My output:

```
{
  "Responses" : [ {
    "head" : "title"
  }, {
    "name" : "vsnu"
  }, {
    "head" : "title"
  }, {
    "name" : "anothervsnu"
  } ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "Responses" : [ {
    "head" : "title",
    "name" : "vsnu"
  }, {
    "head" : "title",
    "name" : "anothervsnu"
  } ]
}
```

Please help me writing a correct JOLT spec for the above expected output. 
I am not able to populate the "title" while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "title": {
        "*": {
          "$(1)": "Responses.[#2].head",
          "@": "Responses.[#2].name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```